# Sufficient condition for a polynomial to be a characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

Let $A\in \operatorname{Mat}_{n\times n}(F),~F$ being a field, satisfies $p(x)\in F[x]$ where $\deg p(x)=n$ and $p(x)$ is a monic polynomial. Can we say $p(x)=\chi_A(x)?$

Comment: The question is very unclear (as witnessed by the contradictory answers). Can you please clarify on what you actually meant?

Comment: A reformulation won't do harm, but title + question taken together look unambiguous to me. But perhaps I am just taking the wrong interpretation ;-)

Comment: The question is written in symbol-laden mumbo jumbo. But I agree with Andreas that it's fairly clear what the OP tried to ask (even if he didn't succeed). The question is (I think): given a polynomial, can I always find a matrix having that given polynomial as its characteristic polynomial? The answer is "yes", as given below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to provide a simple example, the $2 \times 2$ zero matrix is a root of all polynomials
$$
x^2 + a x,
$$
for all $a \in F$.

Its characteristic polynomial is $x^2$, of course.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, I think you mean for any monic polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n$ over $F$, there is always a $n$-dimensional matrix corresponding to. This is true as you can always take the corresponding companion matrix.

Comment: In the current form, the question starts with "Let $A\in\operatorname{Mat}_{n\times n}(F)$". That means that $A$ is fixed.

Comment: Notice that! Instead of giving the OP an answer, IMHO this gives an equivalent condition, which solves all doubts.

Comment: +1 for making a reasonable attempt to interpret the question

Answer (score 2):

No.

While it is true that $\chi_A$ is monic of degree $n$, in general there are many such polynomials, and only a single one of them is $\chi_A$.

Answer (score 1):

No. If $\chi_A(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A$, then $\chi_A(x)+1$ is a degree-$n$ polynomial that is *necessarily* not equal to $\chi_A(x)$. Hence there always exists a degree-$n$ monic polynomial that is not the characteristic polynomial of $A$.

Alternatively, if every arbitrary degree-$n$ monic polynomial $p(x)$ is a characteristic polynomial of $A$, then characteristic polynomials are not unique. Yet, by definition, $\chi_A(x)=\det(xI-A)$, meaning that the characteristic polynomial is uniquely defined.